# How to unit test the role is set in the IamInstanceProfile using cdktf

Tags: typescript, terraform-cdk

I'm writing cdktf (in typescript) to unit test the components to make up some infrastructure. I'm wondering how to test that the role is correctly set in the IamInstanceProfile. Given it's auto generated (using synth), there seems to be no built in way to check.

The code to set iamRole to iamInstanceProfile

```
export class Roles extends Construct {
  iamRole: IamRole;
  iamInstanceProfile: IamInstanceProfile;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    this.iamRole = new IamRole(this, "xxx", {
      assumeRolePolicy: this.getPolicy().json,
      managedPolicyArns: [
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/xxx"
      ],
      name: "xxx"
    });

    this.iamInstanceProfile = new IamInstanceProfile(this, "yyy", {
      name: "test_profile",
      role: this.iamRole.name
    });
  }
```

the unit test

```
    const stack = Testing.synth( new MyStack(new App(), "RunnerTest", baseConfig));
    expect(stack).toHaveResourceWithProperties(IamInstanceProfile, {
      name: 'test_profile',
      role: '<???HOW-TO-GET-THIS-VALUE???>'
    });
```

the error

```
Error: Expected aws_iam_instance_profile with properties {"name":"test_profile","role":"<???HOW-TO-GET-THIS-VALUE???>"} to be present in synthesized stack.
Found 1 aws_iam_instance_profile resources instead:
[
  {
    "name": "test_profile",
    "role": "<AUTO_GENERATED>"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to find the generated value of the role without parsing through the `stack` json output?

Answer (score 0):

The `.name` is a reference and will result in a string with this content `${aws_iam_role.<ID>.name}`. The problem is that the `ID` portion here contains a hash (so that these IDs can remain globally unique while having the same name within and outside a construct) so it's impossible to guess. To find it once you can use snapshot tests or a console log, but to be resilient against change you either need to build a function that finds it or you can use the `.overrideLogicalId("new_id")` function to override the ID of the IAMRole. If you expose the role on the class you can do this even just within the test case.